# volume of the set

Tags: calculus, volume

> Determine the volume of the set $$\{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid
>  \left| x_1- \sqrt{2}x_2 \right| \leq 1, \left| x_1- \sqrt{3}x_2
>  \right| \leq 1 \}$$

We can find that $ \sqrt{2}x_2-1 \leq x_1 \leq 1+ \sqrt{2}x_2$ and $ \sqrt{3}x_2-1 \leq x_1 \leq 1+ \sqrt{3}x_2$. Hence,

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 x_1 \in [\sqrt{3}x_2-1,\sqrt{2}x_2+1] \; \text{if} \; x_2>0\\ 
x_1 \in [\sqrt{2}x_2-1,\sqrt{3}x_2+1] \; \text{if} \; x_2<0
\end{matrix}\right. $

So the volume of this set is $\int_{0}^\infty \int_{\sqrt{3}x_2-1}^{\sqrt{2}x_2+1} 1 dx_1 dx_2+\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{\sqrt{2}x_2-1}^{\sqrt{3}x_2+1} 1 dx_1 dx_2$?

Comment: You can change the variables by setting $$u_1:=x_1-\sqrt{2}x_2\text{ and }u_2:=x_1-\sqrt{3}x_2\,.$$  Then, the given set in the $(u_1,u_2)$-coordinate system is just a square with side $2$.

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski. Does the volume change when we change the variables?

Comment: Yes, it does.  But you should be able to find a relation between a unit volume in the $(u_1,u_2)$-coordinate system and a unit volume in the $(x_1,x_2)$-coordinate system.  See here for example: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx.

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski. It's really helpful

Comment: Anyway, if all fails, I suggest you make a drawing of your set.  My hint is that the set is a parallelogram in the $(x_1,x_2)$-coordinate system.